# React Native input slow after many thousands characters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

Is there a known limit after which the performance drop for the inputs? At 30k characters the input is usable but with noticeable lag. At 65k my app freeze and crash after changes. I need to support input of max 65k characters since it is supported in our web application.

I tried with a basic uncontrolled text input but it is the same as our controlled inputs in ours forms.
`<TextInput placeholder='Placeholder...' autoCorrect={false} />`

Thanks!